# Crop an Android WebView to a circular shape

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to crop an Android WebView to a circular shape, while it still remains interactive (you can scroll, tap buttons etc inside)?

Such as loading http://www.example.com/ like this:

[image]

Comment: You can try giving it custom drawable background of that shape. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675436/android-give-a-webview-rounded-corners)

Comment: just put a circle as a background already..