# Unable to give margin or padding for webview in frame layout

Tags: android, webview

This is my code. I'm unable to align webview exactly below the linear layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="50dip"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etenterurl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:inputType="textUri" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttongo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.0"
        android:text="Go" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0qr-V5OUQ5OFt9C3sDkwhiGpPbxsdUvfBVFx8pA"
/>

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the `WebView` implementation and padding does not work properly,

See: [How to add padding around a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170042/how-to-add-padding-around-a-webview) for a workaround

But i think this is what your are looking for:

A `RelativeLayout` solves this problem with ease! Take a close look at the `layout_below` argument given to the `WebView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etenterurl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:inputType="textUri" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttongo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.0"
            android:text="Go" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your `FrameLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` and then use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    ...

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar" />
```