# Add padding to JavaFX WebView (not Android)

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I want to add padding to a `WebView` in JavaFX, like you can add padding to a label.

I have already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170042/how-to-add-padding-around-a-webview) stack overflow discussion about `WebView` on Android, and it has bugs with the padding. However, I want to add a `WebView` in a `BorderPane` on a desktop application with padding on all sides.

I tried to use `setPadding()` however, this method doesn`t exist.

Is there an alternative for it?

Comment: Why don't u put the padding on the borderpane instead?

Comment: Because I want padding between a label on the top of the borderpane and the webview, which is in the centre of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37935114/230513), you can use the [`BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) *Optional Layout Constraints* to add "Margin space around the outside of the child."

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
BorderPane.setMargin(webView, new Insets(16));
top.setCenter(webView);
```

Comment: Yes, Kaneda already mentioned this. This works perfectly. But I wonder why the `setPadding()` option is not available for WebView. However, my problem is solved, thanks.

Comment: @GregGott This solution is not the same as Kaneda's, either in their comment or their answer. Kaneda's comment says to set the _padding_ of the entire border pane, whereas this answer sets the _margin_ of a specific child node. All within JavaFX. Kaneda's _answer_ drops into the JavaScript/HTML document of the web page and sets the padding there. Also, this answer sets the margin, not the padding. As for why `WebView` does not have a padding property, that's because it extends `Parent` and not `Region`. This makes sense. The style/layout of the web page should be up to the web page.

Comment: @Slaw's insight is correct; also consider for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824164/230513), `StackPane` _is a_ `Region`, so `root.setPadding(new Insets(16))`.

Comment: @Slaw Oh. Thanks for that correction, I was wrong, sorry. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 6):

You can, add a margin bottom to the label, to replace the idea of padding it, or you can use JS when load the WebView and padding inside the html. Like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.padding=\"10%\";void 0");
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to use a margin-bottom, because the code for it looks so dirty. But maybe it's the only possible solution. Inner padding with JS is a really good idea, I didn't think about this before. I don't need this for the current project, but it's really good to know.

Comment: Note that JavaFX does not have a `WebViewClient` class. Android does. Perhaps you got the two mixed up? Though the OP does link to a Q&A that's for Android. However, the question is tagged [tag:javafx] and discusses JavaFX. And the general idea should still be possible in JavaFX.